# I want to accept only odd numbers

Tags: c

I am trying to write a code to accept only odd number. If the number is even, it will ask for another number until an odd number is entered.

If the number is odd, it will continue to run the remaining of the program using that odd value.

I am not sure how to write the syntax for the for loop in this program.

Here is part of the odd number validator code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int num;
    printf("Enter odd value for n: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);


    for(num; num % 2 == 0; num)
    {
        printf("%d is even. TRY AGAIN!: ");
        scanf("%d",&num);
    }


}
```

Comment: Your loop is the same as `while (num % 2 == 0)`.

Comment: thanks that makes more sense actually :P The other silly mistake i realized i was doing is i forgot to put the ",num" in the printf inside the for loop. So i was getting sum garbage value for num.

Comment: You can avoid duplicate `scanf()` by `for(;;) { scanf("%d",&num); if (num%2) break; printf("%d is even. TRY AGAIN!: ", num); }`

Comment: And don't forget to check for `scanf()` failure by returned value.

Answer (score 0):

`#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

```
int num;
odd: //used label
printf("Enter odd value for n: ");
scanf("%d", &num);


if(num%2==0)
```

{

printf("%d is even. TRY AGAIN!: \n",num);

goto odd;

}

printf("%d is Odd ",num);

}